# Como ajustar os grids para sempre ter o mesmo espaço nas alturas

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Estou criando uma tela com bootstrap que irá ter diversos itens [panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-heading) só que da forma que fiz, só fica todos bem ajustados na tela caso o conteúdo tenha a mesma altura, algo que nem sempre irá acontecer, como no exemplo. 
Como arrumar isso?

```
<div class="row">


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 1
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 2
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 3
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 4
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 5
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Titulo XYZ 6
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

**Segue o exemplo rodando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6ptb0c3/)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eita, por que o downvote?

Comment: O que seria o seu ajustado a tela? Uma sugestão que possa dar e trocar a classe do bootstrap  de class="col-xs-6" para class="col-xs-12". Mas depende de como você quer ajustar. Um em baixo do outro? Lado a Lado? etcs. obs: Não fui eu que dei downvote XD

Comment: então, tem que ter as duas colunas, como esta na imagem, mas se o painel 2 é menor que o 1, dai o 3 esta ficando embaixo do 2, até ai sem problemas, desde que o 4 viesse logo embaixo do 1 e não com um espação tão grande como esta

Answer (score 0):

Cara, só encapsular tudo dentro de duas divs maiores metade/metade. Assim:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 1
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 2
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 3
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 4
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 5
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Titulo XYZ 6
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum neque et tempore sint quos earum architecto delectus debitis ut sunt, iusto dolorum, dolor repellendus saepe vel exercitationem eveniet fugiat laboriosam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


</div>
```